# How is a new standby created during a failover in an RDS Multi-AZ deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've read the [Amazon's RDS Multi-AZ documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZSingleStandby.html) which explains how a new primary instance is created during a failure of the primary instance. But then after the standby becomes the primary, **how does the process work for creating a new standby**? Is it created fresh? Is the old primary now used as a standby? What if the old primary volume failed? Do they just replace it with a new one?

Comment: I can't find a documented reference, so I'll leave this as a Comment rather than an Answer. After failover, the Primary is terminated (because something caused a problem). The Secondary becomes the Primary, and a new Secondary is launched in a different AZ than the Primary.